# Using POI to both detect and set column width and to apply text wrap based on that width

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Java 8 and Apache POI 4.1.x here. I need to:

1. Read in a template Excel file, that just has a single row of pre-styled header columns
2. Write a `List<Fizz>` (POJO list) to a *new* Excel file that uses that template

I do this because the template Excel has lots of complicated stylings, and so just using an existing one as a template input was much easier than me trying to manually generate the stylings myself via POI and `CellUtil`.

I have this working perfectly fine like so:

```
List<Fizz> fizzes = getSomehow();

InputStream inp = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my-template.xlsx").openStream();
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

// the header is at row = 0 (0-based rows)
// so start writing the list on the row=1 (1st data/non-header row)
int rowNum = 1;
for (Fizz fizz : fizzes) {
  Row nextRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

  Cell itemNumber = nextRow.createCell(0);
  itemNumber.setCellValue(fizz.getItemNumber());

  Cell description = nextRow.createCell(1);
  description.setCellValue(fizz.getDescription());

  rowNum++;

}

// resize the columns appropriately
for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
}

// export to file system
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some-output.xlsx");
workbook.write(fos);

fos.close();
inp.close();
workbook.close();
```

Everything works great, with one exception: often the `Fizz#description` is pretty lengthy, and is sometimes hundreds of characters long. Because there is no use of text wrapping in my code, and because I use `autoSizeColumn` for all columns, POI is setting the **Description** column width to the length of the longest-description.

Instead, I *now* want to *stop* using `autoSizeColumn` (I think!) and instead:

Force the output file's (in our case, `"some-output.xlsx"`) **Description** column width to be the same as the input template file's Description's column. So if the Description column on `my-template.xlsx` is, say, 54, then I want `some-output.xlsx`'s Description column to also be 54.

If the current row's Fizz description is too long for that width, I want to apply text wrapping so that the column stays fixed (again, in this case, 54) but that the description fits inside of it.

I would like to do this for every column, and ideally, I would like the code to detect what the width is for each column on the template. I say that because I would like to be able to open the template in Excel, change its width manually, save it, then re-run my code and have it pick up on that width change.

**Any ideas on what I can do to accomplish this?**

Comment: Skip the auto-size column call for that column, and style every cell in that column with one with text-wrap enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach**

Set wrap text cell style for whole description column (column `B`) in your template using `Excel`'s `GUI`. Then do using following `getPreferredCellStyle` method to get that column cell style and set it as the preferred cell style for each cell in description column (column `B`).

```
 CellStyle getPreferredCellStyle(Cell cell) {
  // a method to get the preferred cell style for a cell
  // this is either the already applied cell style
  // or if that not present, then the row style (default cell style for this row)
  // or if that not present, then the column style (default cell style for this column)
  CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
  // if no explicit cell style applied then cellStyle.getIndex() is 0 for XSSF
  // or 15 (0xF = the index to the default ExtendedFormatRecord (0xF)) for HSSF
  if ((cell instanceof XSSFCell && cellStyle.getIndex() == 0) || (cell instanceof HSSFCell && cellStyle.getIndex() == 15)) cellStyle = cell.getRow().getRowStyle();
  if (cellStyle == null) cellStyle = cell.getSheet().getColumnStyle(cell.getColumnIndex());
  if (cellStyle == null) cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
  return cellStyle;
 }
```

Then

```
...
Cell description = nextRow.createCell(1);
description.setCellValue(fizz.getDescription());
description.setCellStyle(getPreferredCellStyle(description));
...
```

**Second approach**

Do using [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) to set wrap text cell style for each cell in description column.

```
...
Cell description = nextRow.createCell(1);
description.setCellValue(fizz.getDescription());
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(description, CellUtil.WRAP_TEXT, true);
...
```

**For both approaches**

Do not set `autoSizeColumn` for the description column (column `B`). In your example, only autosize column 0 (`A`) but not column 1 (`B`):

```
...
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
...
```

So the column width of column `B` remains unchanged as width as it is in the template.