# Format a cell to two decimal places POI

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am trying to format the cell to have two digits after the dot. But something is not working for me

```
row.getCell(updatedMDColumnIndex, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).setCellValue(countValue);
    CellStyle style =  row.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    style.setDataFormat(row.getSheet().getWorkbook().createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
    row.setRowStyle(style);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because you are trying to apply a CellStyle into a Row.
Consider applying the style into a Cell object as in:

```
    Cell cell = ...// get the Cell you want.
    cell.setCellStyle(style);  // The style is the CellStyle you created.
```

Comment: It should be mentioned how a row style gets used in Excel. If present a row style gets used when new cells are added to the row in Excel's GUI. But Apache POI does not respect row styles and column styles while `Row.createCell`. So every new created cell must explicitely get its own cell style. I have provided a method `CellStyle getPreferredCellStyle(Cell cell)` multiple times in my answers. For example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707590/using-poi-to-both-detect-and-set-column-width-and-to-apply-text-wrap-based-on-th/59711524#59711524.